# GridView Capabilities

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I was wondering if the `GridView` can do the following:

1. Allow the user to add a new empty row.
2. Have the row be the first one in the grid.
3. Have the row be selected and in edit mode so the user can add information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example here: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article180.aspx

It should be easy enough to put the form that handles the new record at the top, rather than at the bottom.

Comment: Actually I like his method of the row showing up in the footer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is added a new, empty data row to the top of the data table with an ID of -1 (or if a string ID "new" or "empty").  Set the edit index to that row and bind the data.

(Quick and dirty example)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" 
            onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="litColumn1" Text='<%#Bind("column1") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtColumn1" Text='<%#Bind("column1") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="litColumn2" Text='<%#Bind("column2") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtColumn2" Text='<%#Bind("column2") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="litColumn3" Text='<%#Bind("column3") %>' runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtColumn3" Text='<%#Bind("column3") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="saveLink" runat="server" CommandName="update">Save</asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And for the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            Fill_Grid();
    }

    private void Fill_Grid()
    {
        //Create new test data source and columns
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("column1");
        dt.Columns.Add("column2");
        dt.Columns.Add("column3");

        //Sample data
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = 1;
        dr["column1"] = "test1.1";
        dr["column2"] = "test1.2";
        dr["column3"] = "test1.3";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = 2;
        dr["column1"] = "test2.1";
        dr["column2"] = "test2.2";
        dr["column3"] = "test2.3";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Empty row at the top
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = -1;  //-1 is for new rows only
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);    //inserting at 0th position of table

        //Bind data
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.EditIndex = 0;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check ID
        if (e.Keys[0].ToString() == "-1")
        {
            //is a new row, insert data
        }
        else
        {
            //is an update, save data
        }

        //Rebind data
        Fill_Grid();
    }
```